# What does non-dualstack mean in the context of s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to understand the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) in aws for s3 and available endpoints.

From my reading there are 3 types of endpoints you can use to access objects in s3

- virtual hosted style access
- path style access
- [dual-stack endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/dual-stack-endpoints.html)

I feel like I understand what they are, but I am struggling to understand what the difference is between the first 2 and dual-stack. Is the difference that virtual hosted style access and path style access do not work over IPv6 and to achieve this you need to use dual-stack endpoints which supports both protocols?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any domain name in AWS which contains dualstack generally refers that the domain itself will resolve to both IPv4 and IPv6.

The below features are currently not supported in dualstack domains:

- Static website hosting from an S3 bucket
- BitTorrent

Virtual host access simply means that the bucket name is included in the domain name, one of the major benefits is that Amazon allows you to resolve your hostname to an Amazon S3 bucket as long as the bucket name matches the exact domain name i.e. `example.com` would need an s3 bucket of `example.com` which means you can have a DNS record resolve `example.com` to `https://example.com.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com`.

Path based simply means the bucket name is included in the path rather than the domain i.e. in the `example.com` bucket it would be `https://s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com/example.com`.

Both of the above also work for dualstack, for example:

- Virtual host access: `https://example.com.s3.dualstack.aws-region.amazonaws.com`
- Path based: `https://s3.dualstack.aws-region.amazonaws.com/example.com`

Comment: That makes sense but what would be the difference between `https://example.com.s3.dualstack.aws-region.amazonaws.com` and `https://example.com.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: Simply that `https://example.com.s3.dualstack.aws-region.amazonaws.com` would resolve to IPv6 and IPv4. By doing this any clients that already using IPv6 benefit from being able to use this :)

Comment: Thanks this is confirming my suspicion, just so the last piece in my head is clear - `https://example.com.s3.aws-region.amazonaws.com` would only resolve to IPv4 correct?